# Levenshtein cost settings

Tags: text, text-processing, levenshtein-distance

I've been asked to *guess* the user intention when part of expected data is missing. For example if I'm looking to get `very well` or `not very well` but I get only `not` instead, then I should flag it as `not very well`.

The Levenshtein distance for `not` and `very well` is `9` and the distance for `not` and `not very well` is `10`. I think I'm actually trying to drive a screw with a wrench, but we have already agreed in our team to use Levenshtein for this case.

As you have seen the problem above, is there anyway if I can make some sense out of it by changing the *insertion*, *replacement* and *deletion* costs?

P.S. I'm not looking for a hack for this particular example. I want something that generally works as expected and outputs a better result in these cases also.

Comment: Soundex might be a better algorithm: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex. Both "not" and "cup" have the same levelshtein distance. IMO, "if (str.match(/^\s*[nN])) {str='not very well'} else {str='very well'}" is simpler.

Comment: @glennjackman I'm 100% agree with you. That's what I've offered, but the argument was it might not work as expected with other languages rather than English. Thanks anyways, I will bring it up again with our team.

Answer (score 0):

The Levenshtein distance for **not** and **very well** is actually 12.  The alignment is:

```
------not
very well
```

So there are 6 insertions with a total cost of 6 (cost 1 for each insertion), and 3 replacements with a total cost of 6 (cost 2 for each replacement).  The total cost is 12.

The Levenshtein distance for **not** and **not very well** is 10.  The alignment is:

```
not----------
not very well
```

This includes only 10 insertions.  So you can choose **not very well** as the best match.

The cost and alignment can be computed with htql for python:

```
import htql
a=htql.Align()
a.align('not', 'very well')
# (12.0, ['------not', 'very well'])
a.align('not', 'not very well')
# (10.0, ['not----------', 'not very well'])
```